# load more articles button wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I want to create a "load more articles" button that would generate 6 more articles. I have been looking online and found some tutorials, but they are for websites hosted in wordpress. my website only uses wordpress for news articles and posts them to my html page (I dont think its the right way to do it, but its what works for me at the moment)

Here is my site so far: http://futsoc.co/news/overview/recent-news/ (I corrected the link)

Here is what my code looks like so far. I want the new articles to be posted with the same format as the second loop:

I have a loop to show the 6 featured articles

```
<div class="row">

<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=featured&posts_per_page=6' );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
<article class="news-container">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="news-link">
        <div class="news-image">
            <div class="news-img-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-info">
            <p>
                <i class="far fa-clock" style="padding-right:5px;"></i>
                <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
            </p>
            <h5>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h5>
        </div>
    </a>
</article>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

and I have a loop to show the 6 most recent articles (excluding the ones already featured)

```
<div class="row">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
if ( in_array( $post->ID, $do_not_duplicate ) ) continue; ?>

<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
<article class="news-container-small">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="news-link-small">
        <div class="news-image-small">
            <div class="news-img-bg-small" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-info-small">
            <p>
                <i class="far fa-clock" style="padding-right:5px;"></i>
                <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
            </p>
            <h5>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h5>
        </div>
    </a>
</article>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by my website only uses WordPress for news articles and posts them to my html page? do you mean that you generate static html pages from the loop somehow? or you have already built in site using html and you use WordPress for posts and articles only ? which mean that basically portion of your site hosted by WordPress

Comment: yes I already built a website using html and only use wordpress for it to display articles on my html website. I hope that makes sense. and yes, i guess you are right the article pages are hosted by wordpress, but what I am tyrying to implement is on the "news" page, which idnt hosted by wordpress

Comment: it doesn't matter if you have other parts of site using static HTML or not  you can find many answered here or you can follow the tutorials which found follow them and you will have your solution,

Comment: ive tried them, but they all have some kind of instruction to add code to the function.php and index.php in wordpress, but my news page doesnt use those pages

Comment: it's not possible at all that you are not using functions.php beside you don't need to touch index.php only functions.php to include your JavaScript code and some variables

Comment: I am only using functions.php when an article is opened, but on the other pages of my website i do not use wordpress at all, only to call for article titles and thumbnails on the news page.

Comment: look when you request any type of query to WordPress then you are using the functions.php so basically  when call the articles titles and thumbnails then you are using functions.php

Comment: ohh I didnt know that. let me try those other tutorials then and i will check back. thanks